# Fill one textbox with the IP-Host relation in a list

Tags: c#, autocomplete, textbox

I'm just blocked with this one, searched everywhere but there is a tough one to find

In my windowsform C# application that I'm developing in VS Express 2012 I'm trying to achieve the following:

I've a list of IP hostname relation in plain text, like this:

```
99999 10.10.10.10
88888 10.10.10.11
```

etc

1567 lines in total

In the form I've two textbox's, one with autocomplete (the list of items are only the hostnames), the second one should display the IP regarding the hostname entered, as soon as the user select the hostname from the autocomplete sugestion.

Sorry but I'm stuck with this one, help please
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking... Do you need help parsing the text? Or with the autocomplete in the textbox?

Comment: yes, in parsing the text! I really don't know how to manage the _"look to the list of relation and display the IP related to the hostname"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cant you just create a class ? like this

```
class ips
{
    public int ident;
    public string ip;
    public ips(int Ident, string Ip)
    {
        this.ident = Ident;
        this.ip = Ip;
    }
}
//fill the List
const int MAXELEMENTS = 512;

ips[] ipList = new ips[MAXELEMENTS];
ips ipa = new ips(1111, "10.10.10.1");
ips ipb = new ips(2222, "20.20.20.1");
```

and then fire SelectionChangeCommitted event ?

```
public Form1()
{
    ipList[0] = ipa;
    ipList[1] = ipb;

    InitializeComponent();
    cBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
    for(int i = 0; i < ipList.Count(); i++)
    {
        if(ipList[i] != null)
           cBox1.Items.Add(ipList[i].ip);
     }
 }

 private void cBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      tBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(ipList[cBox1.SelectedIndex].ident);
 }
```

i hope this helped you

Answer (score 1):

Right, so we'll take your examples:

```
99999 10.10.10.10
88888 10.10.10.11
```

and parse those into a dictionary, like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> ParseText(string text)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> hostnameDictionary= new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach(var line in text.Trim().Split(Environment.NewLine)))
    {
        string[] textParts = line.Trim().Split(' ');

        if(textParts.Length == 2 && !hostnameDictionary.ContainsKey(textParts[0])
        {
            hostnameDictionary.Add(textParts[0], textParts[1]);
        }
    }
    return hostnameDictionary;
}
```

Note that the above will work **only if** there aren't spaces elsewhere, so if the hostname has a space in it, then the above won't parse it.

Using the method above, you'll get a dictionary which uses the hostnames as keys, so you can very easily find what ip belongs to what dictionary, so for example typing `hostnameDictionary["99999"]` will return the string `"10.10.10.10"`

If this wasn't clear, or you need help with another part, let me know and I'll update the answer.